# Excel Formula difference between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two dates as the following , I want to get the duration spent between them.

```
 6/29/2015 12:18:04 PM
```

Regards,

Comment: In which format?  Day?  Minute?  Hours?

Comment: both three please if possible , I will repeat the result in three cells no problem

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DATEDIF` function to calculate duration

**Syntax** :

```
=DATEDIF(Start_Date, End_Date, Unit) or e.g =DATEDIF(A1,A2,"m").
```

inplace of unit replace the following to get the results

> UNIT  RETURNS

“Y”     Returns the period difference as complete years.

> “M”   Returns the period difference as complete months.
>
> “D”   Returns the number of days in the period.
>
> “MD”  Returns the difference between the days in ‘Start_Date’ and
>   ‘End_Date’.  Here the months and years of the dates are ignored.
>
> “YM”  Returns the difference between the months in ‘Start_Date’ and
>
> ‘End_Date’. Here the days and years of the dates are ignored
>
> “YD”  Returns the difference between the days of ‘Start_Date’ and
>   ‘End_Date’. Here the years of the dates are ignored.

**Sample usage** :

=DATEDIF(A1,A2,"m").

Comment: isn't the command =datediff (with 2 f's?)

Comment: nevermind. datedif is correct. datediff is the VBA equivilant.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** and **A2** like:

[image]

In **A3** use:

```
=A2-A1
```

[image]

and to see the difference is a more "readable" format use:

```
=INT(A2-A1) & " " & TEXT(A2-A1-INT(A2-A1),"hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

The integer portion of the result is whole days difference.